# DISM.exe Return Codes?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, error-handling, dism

I have a program that calls the dism.exe program and it runs a few commands in the background. Right now, I only check for a return code of 0 or anything else in order to show a process failed or succeeded. What could i cross examine the return code with in order to get an accurate return error. Which returns are the DISM referenced to?

Comment: You might wanna look as the DISM API, there is also a section on error codes for troubleshooting https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh825833(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I googled around for probably 20 minutes, and this page never came up once...Thank you

Comment: Well, it's actually the first hit when you enter your question title into Google ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The link provided in the comment [DISMAPI Error Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh825833(v=vs.85).aspx) provides a very few error code, but in my experience, these are not the most common error codes returned by `DISM.exe`.

In my scenarios, I mostly use `dism.exe /Online ...` and here's what I found so far:

- `ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED ~ 3010 (0xBC2)` when `/Add-Package` requires a reboot.
- `ERROR_BAD_FORMAT ~ 11 (0xB)` when you hand `/Add-Package` a package that is not applicable to this operating system (e.g. an x86 package for a x64 Windows)
- `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND ~ 3` when the file you hand to `/PackagePath` doesn't exist
- `ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED ~ 740 (0x2E4)` when you're not running as admin.

Additional Links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes
- https://github.com/jeffkl/ManagedDism/blob/master/dismapi.h